# Euclidean Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

$XYZ$ is a triangle in which $\angle X$ is obtuse. A point $P$ is taken inside the triangle
and $XP$, $YP$, $ZP$ are produced to meet the sides $YZ$, $ZX$, $XY$ at the points $K$, $L$, $M$, respectively. Suppose that $PL = PM$.

> Find the angles of triangle $XYZ$, given that
>
> - $XK$, $YL$, $ZM$ are the angle bisectors of triangle $XYZ$
> - and that $2\;XK = YL$.

Comment: I proved that XYZ is an isosceles triagle; XZ=XY. That means the angle bisector of X will be Perpendicular to YZ (and median).

Comment: After this I get confused. . I dont know how to make pythagoras law and sine law usuful in sovling my problem!

Comment: I placed a drawing in the answer section that meets the above requirements without being isosceles triangle. Could you provide the proof for your claim?

Answer (score 0):

hint: make $LQ \perp YZ , Q$ is on $YZ$, find $\dfrac{LQ}{XK}$

Answer (score 0):

The attached drawing show a case where the above requirements are met but I am not sure there is a single solution

[image]